# Need to create admin user without capability to create user

Tags: user-roles, capabilities

I need to remove user related capabilities(such as 'create_users', 'add_user', 'list_users', etc...) of an admin user.

I tested the code below in an 'init' method.

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$current_user->remove_cap('create_users');
$current_user->remove_cap('add_user');
$current_user->remove_cap('list_users');
```

But I found that still user is able to access interface for managing user(even after refreshing many times). Is there any solution other than creating new role for this?

Comment: Do you want to remove this ability from all the admins in the site? or only for selected one(s)?

Comment: @Maruti Mohanty, only selected one(s).

Answer (score 0):

Adapt the easier way. Install a plugin (Ex. [Members](http://wordpress.org/plugins/members/)) that can manage roles. Create one role with restricted access in your case a role with all the capabilities but not `'create_users', 'add_user', 'list_users',`. Save this new role and assign it to the user you want to grant these restricted privileges.

Comment: thank you, but my site has lot of custom post types and a custom content publishing workflow are there, so it is difficult to integrate to existing system. Anyway thank you and are you sure that there is no way to remove pre-defined capabilities like 'create_users'?.